# Me sale un error relacionado con las tablas de SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

Buenas estoy trabajando con springboot para acceder a los datos desde angular pero no me muestra los datos al hacer un @joinColumn dandome un error de que la clave primaria de la otra tabla es otro nombre lanzando asi el error sqlserverexception.
Adjunto las clases

Clase Controller:

```
  package com.example.servidor.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.servidor.model.Empresa;
import com.example.servidor.model.Enlace;
import com.example.servidor.repository.EmpresaRepository;
import com.example.servidor.repository.EnlaceRepository;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public class EnlaceController {

    @Autowired
    private EnlaceRepository enlaceRepository;
    @Autowired
    private EmpresaRepository empresaRepository;

    @GetMapping("/enlace")
    public List<Enlace> getEnlace() {
        return (List<Enlace>) enlaceRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/enlace")
    void addEnlace(@RequestBody Enlace enlace) {
        enlaceRepository.save(enlace);

    }

    @DeleteMapping("/enlace/{id}")
    public void deleteEnlace(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        if (id != 0) {
            enlaceRepository.deleteById(id);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/empresa")
    public List<Empresa> getEmpresas() {
        return (List<Empresa>) empresaRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/empresa")
    void addEmpresa(@RequestBody Empresa empresa) {
        if (empresa != null) {
            empresaRepository.save(empresa);
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/empresa/{id}")
    public void deleteReservation(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        if (id != 0) {
            for (Empresa empresa : this.getEmpresas()) {
                if (empresa.getId() == id) {
                    empresaRepository.deleteById(id);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Clase Enlace:

```
    package com.example.servidor.model;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Enlace {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "I_ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "V_URL")
    private String url;
    @Column(name = "V_ENTORNO")
    private String entorno;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn 
    private Empresa idEmpresa;

    public Enlace() {

    }

    public Enlace(int id, String url, String entorno) {
        super();
        this.url = url;
        this.entorno = entorno;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        Enlace user = (Enlace) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, user.id) && Objects.equals(url, user.url) && Objects.equals(entorno, user.entorno)
                && Objects.equals(idEmpresa, user.idEmpresa);
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getEntorno() {
        return entorno;
    }

    public void setEntorno(String entorno) {
        this.entorno = entorno;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Empresa getEmpresa() {
        return idEmpresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresa(Empresa empEmpresa) {
        this.idEmpresa = empEmpresa;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Enlace [id=" + id + ", url=" + url + ", entorno=" + entorno + ", idEmpresa=" + idEmpresa + "]";
    }



}
```

Clase EMPRESA:

```
   package com.example.servidor.model;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Empresa {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "I_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "V_NOMBRE")
    private String nombre;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idEmpresa", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Enlace> enlaces;

    public Empresa() {

    }

    public Empresa(int id, String nombre, Enlace enlace) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.id = id;
        this.enlaces = Stream.of(enlace).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        this.enlaces.forEach(x -> x.setEmpresa(this));

    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Enlace> getEnlaces() {
        return enlaces;
    }

    public void setEnlaces(Set<Enlace> enlaces) {
        this.enlaces = enlaces;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Empresa [id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", enlaces=" + enlaces + "]";
    }


}
```

La clave primaria en mi base de datos de la tabla empresa es I_ID, y mi clave primaria en la tabla enlace I_ID, y la clave foranea se encuentra en la tabla enlace con el nombre I_ID_EMPRESA.

Ahora paso por aqui el error que me lanza springboot

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: El nombre de columna 'id_empresa_i_id' no es válido.
```

Si accedo a la pagina web localhost:8080/empresa me lanza este error:

```
could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.servidor.model.Empresa["enlaces"])
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema, creo, es que JPA no sabe hacer el join, ya que no se le indica la columna de la tabla, prueba a cambiar el `@OneToMany` de `Empresa` de esta forma.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "I_ID_EMPRESA")
private Set<Enlace> enlaces;
```

La definición en la parte del `Enlace` tampoco indica correctamente el nombre de la columna, yo la cambiaría por:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name= "I_ID_EMPRESA")
private Empresa empresa;
```

En JPA, la idea es que se trabaje con clases y atributos en Java y que los "joins" en BBDD los haga de forma transparente, por ejemplo, para acceder al `id` de la emrpesa desde el enlace, habría que llamar a `enlanceX.getEmpresa().getId()`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pero al hacer eso me sale otro error, este es el error que lanza ahora:  SQL Error: 207, SQLState: S0001
2020-02-07 11:01:25.977 ERROR 19876 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : El nombre de columna 'id_empresa' no es válido.

Comment: @AntonioJesús, he modificado el código con el nombre correcto de la columna, prueba ahora